# Counting the occurrence of each number in prime factors of an integer

Tags: java, algorithm, math, primes

I want to count the number of each prime factor of an integer. For an example 18=2^1*3^2. I want to get all exponent part of each prime number. For number 18, it is 1+2=3.
Below is the program which generates all the prime factors of an integer.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1)
        System.out.print(n + ", ");
```

For input 18, this program prints 2, 3, 3, . As for completing my requirement, to count the occurrence of each prime factor, i can first add them all to a list, then a `for` loop from starting to ending of the list can count the occurrence of each number. But this idea doesn't seem good to me. Unnecessary i am adding one `for` loop, for all prime factors, which just tells me that this prime factor comes n times in the list.
Any better approach to get the number of individual number of prime factors of an integer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Just count how many times your inner loop is executed.

Comment: `i * i <= n` is slightly faster than `i <= n / i`

Comment: @n.m. Nope. I don't want to count the total number of factors. I want to count that `for all prime factors of an integer, how many times every prime factor is occurring` . For example integer 18 can be written as 2^1*3^2. I want to count all the occurance of all factors. As in the prime factor of integer 18, 2 comes 1 time and 3 comes 2 times. So my final ans is `2, 3`. What you are saying will print the number of prime factors, which is 3 in this example.

Comment: I understood that the first time around. You need to reset the counter before entering the inner loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Writing `i<=n/i` will always keep the range of outer `for` loop from `2` to `n/i`. Higher the `i` will keep shorter the range. But writing `i*i<=n` will keep the range from `2` to `n`. You might be right. Can you please explain your idea in a bit detail. Any way thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Ravi: the two conditions are equivalent (`i*i<=n` if and only if `i<=n/i`), provided nothing overflows. What Peter is saying is that the compiler+JIT isn't smart enough to figure that out and do the faster calculation regardless of which you write.

Comment: @Peter the main reason to write `i <= n/i` is to avoid overflow. `i*i <= n` overflows *real* easy on `Int`s.

Comment: @Will: since `i` increases from 2, you'll only have overflow in `i*i` if `n` doesn't fit in an `int` to begin with (well, strictly speaking, if it's greater than 32767^2). So you're on the verge of having problems even with the safer calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yy, just as @attila and @robert said:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.TreeMap; 

public class Test{
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> factors = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(); 

        for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
            int count = 0; 

            while (n % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i + ", ");
                n /= i;
                count ++; 
            }
            if( count > 0 ) 
                factors.put( i, count ); 
        }
        if (n > 1){
            System.out.print(n + ", ");
            factors.put( n, 1 ); 
        }
        System.out.println(); 

        System.out.println( "-------------" ); 
        for( Integer factor : factors.keySet() ){
            System.out.println( factor + "^" + factors.get( factor ) ); 
        }
    }
}
```

i'm using a treemap because it keeps the factors in their natural order, which is neat :) 
you could also use a hashmap which should be a bit faster. but the implementation of the prime decomposition should be so slow that i don't think it matters much :)

Comment: I apologize for not asking the question correctly. Let say i have an integer 18. `18=2^1*3^2` i want the exponent number for each prime factor. here exponent factors are 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works fine. Initially i was thinking to make use of any `java collection` but i thought that mathematically if there exists any other solution, then i should implement that. Because at the end i just want `prime_num_1^any_integer*prime_num_2^any_integer*prime_num_3^any_integer.....`

Comment: you don't need no treemap here. First, since you test `i`s in increasing order, you can only get factors in increasing order. Second, if all you do is print, why not print them out each inside the inner loop, under `if (count > 0) ...` (and one more possible printout in the end, if `n>1`)? The only need for TreeMap is if you'd want to return it.

Comment: "The only need for TreeMap is if you'd want to return it."
yes, that's exactly why i put it there :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are executing `n/=i;`, you are encountering a factor.  So by incrementing a counter (Starting from 0) at that point, you get the total number of factors at the end of the factorization process.

Note that you need an extra if for properly handling prime numbers.  For primes you do not find any factors, so the counter will be 0 -- you need to set it to 1 after the loop in this case (one factor: itself)

Comment: Nope. I don't want to count the total number of factors. I want to count that `for all prime factors of an integer, how many times every prime factor is occurring` . For example integer 18 can be written as 2^1*3^2. I want to count all the occurance of all factors. As in the prime factor of integer 18, 2 comes 1 time and 3 comes 2 times. So my final ans is `2, 3`. What you are saying will print the number of prime factors, which is 3 in this example.

Comment: So, for your example with 18, you want to see the 1 and the 2, not the total, 3, correct?

Comment: @DavidConrad `18=2^1*3^2` i want the exponent number for each prime factor. here exponent factors are 1 and 2.

Comment: Maybe you should re-word your question.  This part lead me believe you were after the total factor count: _I want to count the exponent part of each prime number. For number 18, it is 1+2=3._

Comment: About handling primes: OP already has that, with `if (n > 1)` at the end of his code. At that point, if `n>1`, the counter must be incremented in all cases.

Comment: FWIW I too was mislead by the confusing formulation to believe the OP wanted the sum of exponents.